# How to get excerpt in custom field value?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

On my WordPress website I have a custom field where I would like to add the excerpt of my post into the custom field value.

My code:

```
function mk_set_default_custom_fields($post_id)
{
if ( $_GET['post_type'] != 'page' ) {
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'key', 'value');

}

return true;
}
```

How can I place the excerpt of my post into the `add_post_meta` value once I hit the publish button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$post` Object and with help of it you can set `value` as

```
$post->post_excerpt
```

Just For info of other available options

```
$post->post_author
$post->post_date
$post->post_date_gmt
$post->post_content
$post->post_content_filtered
$post->post_title
$post->post_excerpt
$post->post_status
$post->post_type
$post->comment_status
$post->ping_status
$post->post_password
$post->post_name
$post->to_ping
$post->pinged
$post->post_modified
$post->post_modified_gmt
$post->post_parent
$post->menu_order
$post->guid
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but it is not working. I need to add the arguement $post to the function right? I did that and added $post->post_excerpt as the value but it did not work, and I also got an error message Warning: Missing argument 2 for mk_set_default_custom_fields() and Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by pluggable.php

Comment: @Denish: Can you please mention the source for it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the array in your desired custom post like this in your `functions.php`

```
$args = array(
    // by writing these lines an custom field  has been added to CMS
   'supports' => array('title','editor','author','excerpt') 
);
```

For retrieving at the front end

```
echo $post->post_excerpt; // this will return you the excerpt of the current post
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this because that would lead to duplication of your content. But, it looks like your function is hooked to `save_post`. If this is the case, you can get the except from the `$_POST['post_except']` variable. Just don't assume that that variable will always be set because `save_post` is called in a few different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_field_save' );
function my_custom_field_save( $post_id )
{
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_excerpt_field', get_the_excerpt($post_id), true);
    }
}
```

This will `save/update` the custom field (`custom_excerpt_field`) every time you add/update a post.
On the front end, to get the custom field, use (when inside loop)

```
$custom_excerpt_field_data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_excerpt_field', true);
```

Use this (when outside of the loop)

```
global $post;
$custom_excerpt_field_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_excerpt_field', true);
```